Buoyant force on a stick making an angle theta with the vessel
I was solving this question

The answer of the question uses balancing of torques.
It uses $L=0.5$m

I have problem with the fact that they have used buoyant force $F = \rho V g$. Marking the net forces due to pressure difference and taking a small element of volume $dV$, we see the net force due to pressure is acting upwards perpendicular to the rod. The net buoyant force is just the $\sin\theta$ component of the force caused by pressure. I have been trying to prove mathematically that the buoyant force is still $\rho Vg$ but have failed. I was hoping someone could help me out or point out if my concepts are wrong.
I agree the buoyant force is $\rho Vg$ in most cases but I just wanted to prove this follows for the case above :).

I can't read the dimensions in the question description.

@BobD the length of the wooden plank is given as 2L meters and the height of water is 1L meters. In the answer, L has been assumed to be 0.5 m.

Divide the underwater world into two parts - the water and the stick.
Suppose the water disappeared, leaving the stick. The force on the stick would be the weight of the stick.
Suppose you replaced the stick with water that had the same shape. Water is denser than the stick. The force on the water would be the weight of the water, which is greater than the weight of the stick.
Suppose instead the stick disappeared, leaving a hole. Suppose you filled the hole with water. The water would be motionless. That is the force from the water around it would be just enough to hold up the stick shaped water. The upward force would be the weight of the water needed to fill the hole.
The force from the surface of the water pressing on the stick is the same as that on the stick shaped water. The total force on the stick is its own weight downward + the weight of the stick shaped water upward. This is a net force upward.
You don't need to know details like the angle of the stick or the fact that the stick is a straight cylinder to know this. You just need to know the weight of the stick and the weight of the water it displaces.

That is a nice way of solving the problem, thank you! I was trying to follow a more mathematical approach by inspecting small elements but got stuck when I had to get the vector sum of all small df's caused by pressure difference.

Pressure is important. It will be worth your while to get comfortable with it. But getting bogged down in a complicated calculation may not be the best introduction.
